# Переход на PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony2

В общем есть сайт на symfony меняю драйвер на pdo_pgsql, фэйлится фиксура которая создает юзера default.

> INSERT INTO user (Usr_Username, Usr_Email,
>
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"

В общем система хочет чтобы user был в кавычках так как есть такая же переменная

Так написана фикстура

```
 $entity = new User();
            $entity->setUsername("root");
            $manager->persist($entity);
 $entity
            ->setPassword("bla")
            ->setEmail("bla@gmail.com")
            ->setFirst("root")
            ->setLast("root")
            ->setOfficePhone("1")
            ->setMobilePhone("1")
            ->setTimeZone("11")
            ->setEnabled(true);
 $manager->flush();
```

В общем как бы это можно было исправить?

Answer (score 3):

В общем оставлю для себя заметку, в User Entity нужно название таблицы написать в 3х кавычках

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="""user""")
 */
```

Дальше по аналогии в общем, если есть проблемы, у меня была только в этом месте.

Answer (score 1):

`user` - [ключевое слово в Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), на мой взгляд, лучше было бы использовать иное название таблицы или префикс.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
```